Difference in kinetic energy when one block has velocity in a system of two blocks connected with inextensible string and other block at rest
Why is there a difference in kinetic energy in case of when a single block in a two rigid block system of masses connected with an inextensible string has a velocity while the other block is at rest and when the string becomes taut and both blocks move with same velocity?

An inextensible string cannot store energy.  The scenario is basically identical to a collision between two objects that leaves them stuck together (completely inelastic).
The simplest non-math way to see this is to shift to a frame where the center of mass of the system is at rest.
In that frame we would see the two blocks moving away from each other.   The kinetic energy of both blocks is non-zero.
When the string becomes taut, the tension in the string will slow the blocks.   Since the string forces them to have identical velocities, and the total momentum of the system is at rest, the final configuration must have both blocks at rest. In this frame, both blocks have zero kinetic energy after the "collision".   Kinetic energy has been lost due to the inelastic nature of the string.
